# How do I sum across certain columns?

Tags: r

I have a data frame called `df` that looks like this:

```
name score1 score2 score3
Joe     1      NA    3
Jane    NA     2     3
```

How do I make a column named `sum` that sums non-empty cells in `score1`, `score2` and `score3`?

Comment: Try reading `?rowSums`...

Answer (score 2):

```
df$sum <- rowSums(df[,2:4], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: na.rm = TRUE removes them.